# How and where to do dynamic height resize of UITextView inside a custom TableCellView, built in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, uitextview

Going crazy...read dozens of "this is how you do it..." answers, that all differ from one another, and none work in my case. I've messed with UITextView frame, bounds, contentSize, etc.  and though I see these change via NSLog, the final output always reverts back to the original size set in the StoryBoard.

Using StoryBoard I placed a read-only UITextView in a subclassed TableViewCell, named GroupChatViewCell.

I then simply load a handful of text strings into the UITextView through Controller's viewDidLoad. The strings are word wrapped and longer than can fit in the defined UITextView frame.

I resize the TableView Cell (which works) in the TableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate and I am trying to resize the UITextView (does not work) in the TableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GroupChatViewCell";

GroupChatViewCell *cell = (GroupChatViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[GroupChatViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// Retrieve the MessageData for the given row
GroupMessageData *aMessageData = [messageThreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.messageLabel setText:aMessageData.msgText];
[cell.messageLabel sizeToFit];

//    [cell.messageLabel layoutIfNeeded];  --> Did try with this, does not work
//    [cell.messageLabel layoutSubviews];  --> Did try with this, does not work

return cell;
}




- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
GroupMessageData *aMessageData = [messageThreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

GroupChatViewCell *cell = (GroupChatViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GrooupChatViewCell"];


UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds), MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [aMessageData.msgText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
return ceil(labelSize.height + 60);
}
```

I end up with an increased size for the TableCell, but not for the UITextView which is unchanged and clipped to the original size as set in StoryBoard, and only showing the 3 lines of text that fit.

What do I need to do, and where, to expand the UITextView's height to the full size allocated in the Cell and properly display all lines of text???

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the frame of the UITextView from inside the table cell controller. For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
GroupMessageData *aMessageData = [messageThreadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

GroupChatViewCell *cell = (GroupChatViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GrooupChatViewCell"];

UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds), MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [aMessageData.msgText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[cell adjustTextViewHeight];

return ceil(labelSize.height + 60);
}
```

And in your GroupChatViewCell.m:

```
- (void) adjustTextViewHeight{
CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, self.textView.contentSize.height);
}
```

This should change the height of the textView as well. Also, if you have a maximum height for the cell, you can use the MIN function to choose the right height. For example:

Instead of : `self.textView.contentSize.height`
you can have: `MIN (maxHeight, self.textView.contentSize.height)`

Answer (score 0):

Well... I have finally found out what was happening...and this is something I have not seen mentioned in any thread I've looked at...

It turns out that AutoLayout mode was on, by default, as indicated in the File Inspector window. Yet I did not actively use AutoLayout, and I certainly never looked at the File Inspector.

From what I can gather then, this is how AutoLayout behaves:
- if you turn it OFF, then you are in total control of all sizing & placement.
- if you leave it ON (as it is by default) and actively manage the constraints of your views, then AutoLayout will adjust size & position.
- if you leave it ON, and do NOT actively manage the constraints, then it looks like AutoLayout may override your code for sizing views to maintain the original sizes that were set for the views in your StoryBoard.

So simply turning AutoLayout off solved the problem. And turning AutoLayout on and setting top & bottom constraints for the UITextView and its container cell also solved the problem.